# Is there any way to increase width of detailTextLabel in UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I want to know if it is possible to increase the width of detailTextLabel in UITableViewCell.
I have referred this [UITableViewCell class](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but I did not find anything useful.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Note :** I do not want to use CustomCell.

**Update 1:** Reason why I want to do like this :

Actually I am parsing data from XML and I am showing product specifications in a UITableViewCell labels. But I do not know the exact length of String for that are being displayed in labels thus I can't determine the height of label and its cell and value is truncated as shown in image with red rectangle.

Please have a look at the image to have it in a more clear way:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try subclassing `UITableViewCell` and override the default `-(void)layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: Pal, You meant Using CustomCell?

Comment: What do you mean by CustomCell ? If you're talking about drawing your custom cell in InterfaceBuilder and loading it from a NIB, no, that's not my solution. Subclassing allows you to quickly extend the "classic" UITableViewCell class by just changing one of its method.

Comment: I updated question. I think answer of Chris Garrett will help me..Thanks..I accept your answer right now

Answer (score 0):

```
[cell.detailTextLabel setFrame:aBiggerFrame];
```

Comment: Beware, by doing so, you need to keep track yourself of orientation change events, and update all visible cells when they occur. Subclassing is a better way to go IMHO.

Comment: Agreed, subclassing is definitely a better method, but the OP said that he doesn't want to use a custom cell.

Comment: By "custom cell" I hear "cell loaded from a NIB", but well, you might be right about it. Either way, he has the two solutions at his disposal now!

Comment: As long as detailTextLabel has the right autoresizing mask, changes in the contentView size due to rotation will be propagated to it, you don't necessarily need any manual updating.

Comment: I tried :
    cell.textLabel.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 355, 50);
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
but nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

You can do a customCell like @Cyrille said.

Here is a link:

http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder